# Adding Preview Thumbnails in jwplayer, how to generate vtt file in rails and how to integrate in my rails jwplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

```
      <div style="width:100%;height:auto;">
        <% if @play.image_or_video==1 %>
            <div id='playereVfNVznTGxrg'></div>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                jwplayer('playereVfNVznTGxrg').setup({
                    <%# movie = Jwthumbs::Movie.new(@play.video)%>
                    <%# movie.create_thumbs! %>
                    autostart: true,
                    heading: "Share this video",
                    sharing: {
                        code: encodeURI("<iframe src='http://example.com/embed/12345.html' />"),
                        link: "http://example.com/page/12345/"
                    },
                    logo: {
                        file: '/assets/logo.png',
                        link: 'http://staging.kovered.co'
                    },
                    tracks: [{
                        file: "/assets/myThumbnails.vtt",
                        kind: "thumbnails"
                    }],
                   </script>
        <% elsif @play.image_or_video==0 %>
            <img src="<%= @play.video %>" class="img-responsive" alt="<%= @play.title %>">
        <% else %>
            <%= @embed_video.html_safe %>
        <% end unless @play.nil? %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In the `tracks` there is the path of vtt file but how could i generate vtt file for jwplayer in my rails project???
I am using jWplayer7.1